# How to solve for $θ$ in $π/4 - \theta + 26.6 \cos \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the inverse of this, to solve for $\theta$ in terms of $\phi$:

$$ \phi=\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta+26.6°\cos{\theta}$$

I can rearrange this equation a bit, but even back in the days when trigonometry was much fresher in my mind, my math classes really tried hard to avoid dealing with inverse trig functions, to the point of always writing, say, "$\tan θ$ = blah" rather than "$θ = \arctan$ blah". I've tried to find an online equation solver to handle this, but all they do for me so far in just rearrange things a bit, never isolating θ.

In case anyone is interested, this is for some updates to a Prague Astronomical Clock simulator I'm working on, the current release version of which can be found here: https://shetline.com/orloj/

Comment: You cannot extract $\theta$ from this equation (no analytical solution). You can only get numerical approximations.

Comment: Thanks, @Lelouch. I thought about generating a table of values from this, then dumping that data into a polynomial curve-fit generator. Is that a reasonable approach?

Comment: You already have very well known and easy way to solve equations numerically (e.g Newron's method), why not use them ?

Comment: Have a look at Kepler's equation $x=y-a\sin(y)$, it has a sine but maybe you can connect it to your problem. As already said, similarly for Kepler's equation there's no closed form but good approximations

Comment: Sorry, not well known to me! 

Comment: @Lelouch, was "Newron" a typo for "Newton"? If so, yes, that I know, and I've solved a lot of other astronomical calculations that way before. I was just hoping for something faster and more concise.

Comment: Notice that $\phi(\pi/4-\theta)=\theta+26.6^\circ\sin\theta$

Comment: A common technique when solving Kepler's equation via Newton's method when plotting orbits is to base the initial Newton approximation for the current point on the previously calculated point. Either just use the point directly, or add an appropriate delta. I assume you can also use that technique with your clock.

Answer (score 3):

Working with radians and whole numbers, you want to solve for $\theta$ the equation
$$\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta+\frac{133  }{900}\pi\cos(\theta)$$ which is impossible and would require some numerical method.

However, you could have *approximations*. For example, using the $\large 1,400$ years old approximation
$$\cos(\theta) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4\theta^2}{\pi ^2+\theta^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq \theta\leq\frac \pi 2$$ you just need to solve the cubic equation
$$900 \theta ^3+ (900 \phi +307 \pi )\theta ^2+900 \pi ^2 \theta +\pi ^2(900  \phi
   -358 \pi )=0$$ Its discriminant is always negative; so, only one real root. Using the hyperbolic method with
$$p=\pi ^2-\frac{(900 \phi +307 \pi )^2}{2430000} >0 \qquad \text{if} \qquad -\pi \leq \phi \leq \pi$$
$$q=\frac{2 \phi ^3}{27}+\frac{307 \pi  \phi ^2}{4050}+\frac{2524249 \pi ^2 \phi
   }{3645000}-\frac{5004810557 \pi ^3}{9841500000}$$ So, the *approximate* solution is
$$\color{red}{\theta_0=-2\sqrt{\frac p 3}\sinh\Bigg[\frac 13 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 q}{2 p}\sqrt{\frac  3p} \right) \Bigg]-\left(\frac{\phi }{3}+\frac{307 \pi }{2700}\right)}$$

Trying for $\color{red}{\phi=\frac \pi k}$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 20 & 0.912116 &  0.912381 \\
 19 & 0.906055 &  0.906330 \\
 18 & 0.899312 &  0.899598 \\
 17 & 0.891765 &  0.892063 \\
 16 & 0.883260 &  0.883571 \\
 15 & 0.873603 &  0.873928 \\
 14 & 0.862541 &  0.862882 \\
 13 & 0.849745 &  0.850103 \\
 12 & 0.834771 &  0.835147 \\
 11 & 0.817008 &  0.817405 \\
 10 & 0.795596 &  0.796015 \\
 9  & 0.769278 &  0.769719 \\
 8  & 0.736138 &  0.736601 \\
 7  & 0.693112 &  0.693592 \\
 6  & 0.634955 &  0.635439 \\
 5  & 0.551854 &  0.552309 \\
 4  & 0.422936 &  0.423284 \\
 3  & 0.193670 &  0.193770
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, very few iterations of Newton method
$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n+\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta_n+\frac{133  }{900}\pi\cos(\theta_n)-\phi }{1+\frac{133}{900} \pi  \sin (\theta_n ) }$$

Trying for $k=12.345$, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 0.8402168627 \\
 1 & 0.8405869087 \\
 2 & 0.8405868929
\end{array}
\right)$$

Notice that one sigle iteration of Halley method gives $\theta_1=0.8405868929$ (!!).

In other words, we *almost* have the analytical solution.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you have looks similar to Kepler's equation, which is not a suprise as yours is derived from an astronomical clock and Kepler's equation models celestial movement. Kepler's equation is given by
$$y(x)=x-a\sin(x),$$
where we usually are interested in $x(y)$. Taking a closer look at your equation
$$\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta+a\cos(\theta)$$
we can perform a change of variables $\theta\to-\theta'-\frac{\pi}{2}$ which yields
$$\phi-\frac{3\pi}{4}=\theta'-a\sin(\theta').$$
This equation can be solved numerically or via approximations by power series. One such power series in terms of Bessel functions is given by
$$\theta'=\Big(\phi-\frac{3\pi}{4}\Big)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n}J_n(an)\sin\left(n\Big(\phi-\frac{3\pi}{4}\Big)\right),\quad a\leq 1,\quad \phi\in \Big[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}\Big].$$
Backsubstitution then gives as final result:
$$\boxed{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}-\phi-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n}J_n(an)\sin\left(n\Big(\phi-\frac{3\pi}{4}\Big)\right)}$$
with the same restrictions on $a$ and $\phi$ as above.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the particular astronomical clock I'm modeling was built nearly two centuries before Kepler's work, when astronomers were still thinking in terms of perfect circles. The clock is essentially an astrolabe with mechanical wheels and pointers attached. The angle transform I'm dealing with is the conversion of an angle from the center of clock to its edge to the angle from the off-center axis of the ecliptic wheel (which is also the center of the clock) to the edge of that wheel, and hopefully back again.

Comment: The reason for the "π/4 -" has nothing to do with astronomy, but a switch from the astronomical coordinate space to the SVG graphic coordinate space, where y increases downward, and angles start with 0° at 12:00, increasing clockwise.